# Accessing req.body values in express

Tags: json, node.js, mongodb, express, post

I'm working on a REST API node/express app. For my 'signup' route, where a user uses the api to sign up for the service, it takes a POST'ed JSON object. Inside this function I want to check against the mongo db to make sure that this user doesn't already exist.

The problem is I need to get the username from the posted json information, but every attempt I have made has failed. The lines that attempt to log the req.body.username and req.body.password always return 'undefined'. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the code I have so far is below:

```
exports.signup = function(req, res) {

  // todo: somehow verify that username, password, email and phone number are all provided.
  // do not write into the collection unless we know all the information has been provided.
  // maybe access the JSON elements to make sure they are not null
  // todo: also make sure a record doesn't already exist for this uer

  var user = req.body;

  // need to get the username here somehow
  var JSONuser = JSON.stringify(user);
 // console.log('user: ' + user);
  console.log('userJSON: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
  console.log('username: ' + req.body.username);
  console.log('password: ' + req.body.password);

  db.collection('users', function(err, collection){
    //if ( collection.findOne({}) ) { // make sure the user doesn't already exist here
        collection.insert(user, {safe:true}, function(err, result){
          if(err){
            res.send({'error':'An error has occured'});
          } else {
            console.log('Success: ' + JSON.stringify(result[0]));
            res.send(result[0]);
          }
        })
    //}
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

By default in express, you don't have access to those variables through dot syntax. You would have to parse the response. Luckily, we have a package for that.

Use [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) middle ware for easy access to post variables.

```
// install it
bash$: npm install body-parser    

// require it in your project
bodyParser = require('body-parser');

// `use` it in your express app
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true}));

// now you your post values are available on the req.body.postVariableName
```

I use this in almost all of my projects, it just makes it easy.

*** EDIT ***

I looked at your repo and everything actually looks fine as it pertains the reading of parsed values; however, they way you are `console logging` them may be where you are getting confused. I rewrote your signin route so I could explain better.

```
exports.signin = function(req, res) {

    var user = req.body;
    console.log('req.body: ' + JSON.stringify(user));
    console.log('Signing In As User: ' + user.username);
    console.log('Password: ' + user.password);
    res.send('You just signed in!');

}
```

I tested this my opening up another terminal and curling a JSON post.

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username":"testuser","password":"testpassword"}' http://localhost:3000/signin
```

As you can see it should work.

Some things worth mentioning. When you wrote `console.log('req.body: ' + req.body);`. You are not going to see the data you want. You are going to see `req.body: [object]` in the output because javascript is going to render this as req.body.toString() which is just the identifier. If you want to post the code, use `JSON.stringify(req.body)` or use `console.dir(req.body)`.

Second, `req.body` will just give u access the body object.

```
// this is just user.toString() which is again [object]
console.log('Signing In As User: ' + user);

// You need to use the dot syntax to get user.username
console.log('Signing In As: " + user.username);
```

If you are stilling seeing issues, its because of the way you are making posts localhost, not because of your code.

Comment: So I read that around online, and set up my app.js file to do that, but it's still showing as 'undefined' in the console output. Here's the pastebin of my main app.js file: http://pastebin.com/raw/5kSn8eLE

Any insight into why I'm still running into a problem?

Comment: do you have your repo on github, I don't see a problem with the code you have, I would need to see more.

Comment: Sure, thanks for looking at it, the github is available at: https://github.com/aaronhesse/restapitest

Comment: Ok I made your recommended change to how console.log is logging information. However, I still am not seeing the correct output. On a second note, if you can tell there is a newuser.json file on my github account. This is because when I try to include the JSON on the command line for curl, I actually get an "invalid_json" error printed out. So when I use the newuser.json file and reference it for curl, curl will no longer error out. But still, I do not see the correct information being logged to the console (in any case). (This is using curl version 7.53.1)

Comment: @user1250991 can you please push your updated code to the repo.

Comment: I don't understand, it works for me. `curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST -d '{"username": "davidwalsh","password": "something"}' http://localhost:3000/signup` The only error i see is that you are sending   res.send('You just signed up!'); which closes the response for res. So the code crashes. Remove this.

Comment: Ok, I removed the res.send line, and i'm definitely still getting the curl error, i'll paste it here for completnesses sake. I'll continue to research it though. Based on the error it appears to be related to the bodyparser lib, maybe the curl request is working, but the error message is actually the response from the server....

Comment: Error: invalid json<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\Preferred User\****\no
de_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at C:\Users\Pre
ferred User\****\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:108:18<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;
at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Preferred User\****\node_modules\raw-body\index.js
:262:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\Preferred User\****\node_modules\r
aw-body\index.js:251:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at IncomingMessage.onEnd (C:\Users\Pref
erred User\****\node_modules\raw-body\index.js:307:7)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at emit
None (events.js:86:13)<br> &nbsp;

Comment: I just updated body-parser to 1.17.1, i think it was at 1.13.3 or something. i now get a different error:

SyntaxError: Unexpected token &#39;<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at parse (C:\Users\Preferre
d User\****\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:83:15)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp
;at C:\Users\Preferred User\****\node_modules\body-parser\lib\read.js:116:18<b
r> &nbsp; &nbsp;at invokeCallback (C:\Users\Preferred User\****\node_modules\r
aw-body\index.js:262:16)<br> &nbsp; &nbsp;at done (C:\Users\Preferred User\****

Comment: So it definitely seems environmental in nature, and that the error/printout that I'm seeing is definitely a response from the server.

Comment: Ok. So I changed the command-line inclusion of the json data to instead deliver the payload from the newuser.json file that you can see in the repo. When I do this, everything works.

So I'm not sure what is going on with specifying a JSON payload on the commandline of curl, but the server changes seem to work now, and I can advance to the next part of my code. Thanks for the help.